# How do I stop ASUSTek AlertHelper from asking for password every time I log in?

Tags: windows-10, uac

Every time I log in into Windows 10 I get prompted for the password of my admin user by ASUSTek AlertHelper:

[image]

Comment: do you need it? Would disabling it starting up automatically be an option?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm not entirely surely. Since I'm overclocking, my guess is I do.